# remove dell optimizer service - powershell

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

Problem -
Unable to uninstall dell optimizer service

Long version -
i am looking to write what should be a very basic script for removing dell optimizer. when its fully installed and i run get-package I get the following.
When this is uninstalled by piping into uninstall-package. we are still left with dell optimizer service.
this is after stopping the services as well.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Package -Name *optimizer*

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName                               
----                           -------          ------                           ------------                               
Dell Optimizer                 2.0.651.0        C:\Program Files\Dell\DellOpt... msi                                        
DellOptimizerUI                2.0.651.0        C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\D... msi                                        
Dell Optimizer Service         2.0.651.0                                         Programs
```

[dell optimizer service in programs and features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PBdO.png)
the uninstall string as below when run does not accept -remove or -runfromtemp  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{286A9ADE-A581-43E8-AA85-6F5D58C7DC88}\DellOptimizer.exe" -remove -runfromtemp

```
+ ... A9ADE-A581-43E8-AA85-6F5D58C7DC88}\DellOptimizer.exe" -remove -runfro ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-remove' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:199
+ ... -A581-43E8-AA85-6F5D58C7DC88}\DellOptimizer.exe" -remove -runfromtemp
+                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-runfromtemp' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

the exe is located at

C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{286A9ADE-A581-43E8-AA85-6F5D58C7DC88}\DellOptimizer.exe

I have used 7zip to unpackage the .exe to see if there was an uninstall file but to no avail.

I believe it has something to do with its providername being program and also the dell optimizer service does not appear when you search for the below in ciminstance.
Im unsure how to find which CIMclass it would fall into as it could be a step in the right direction

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product | Sort-Object
```

Has anyone done something like this before? or anything i could try?

Comment: Something quoted has to be run differently, like with the call operator: `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{286A9ADE-A581-43E8-AA85-6F5D58C7DC88}\DellOptimizer.exe' -remove -runfromtemp`

Answer (score 0):

i worked it out. it was a silly mistake and needed to run the uninstall string in command prompt

```
#stop dell optimizer services
Get-Service -Name "DellOptimizer" | Stop-Service



#Get Dell Optimizer from registry
$uninstallstring = get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "optimizer service"}



#get the uninstall string for dell optimizer
$uninstallstring = $removeapp.UninstallString



#add the silent parameter and run throguh cmd to uninstall
cmd /c $uninstallstring -silent
```

Answer (score 0):

fix for your script

```
#stop dell optimizer services
Get-Service -Name "DellOptimizer" | Stop-Service

#Get Dell Optimizer from registry
$uninstallstring = get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "optimizer service"}

#get the uninstall string for dell optimizer
$uninstallstring = $uninstallstring.UninstallString

#add the silent parameter and run throguh cmd to uninstall
cmd /c $uninstallstring -silent
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just follow their documentation and download the exe.  extract it to get the DellOptimizer.exe package it up with a simple powershell script that run DellOptimizer.exe /remove /silent